# Windows XP: Black screen on host after RDC

Tags: windows, windows-xp

I have a laptop running xp sp3. RDC works fine.

I have set the laptop to do nothing when the lid closes, the screen turns off when the lid closes.  When I open it, the screen comes back on.

However if I RDC to it, then the next time I open the lid, the screen never turns back on. The computer is still running, and all its network connections work fine, but the screen never turns back on!

Anyone have any idea what this might be? I have just done a fresh install and have all latest drivers.

Answer (score 0):

My first bet would be an issue with the video driver, possibly a bug. Hopefully there are a few different versions of the driver available and I would try them out and see if that resolves it.

Answer (score 0):

Could be ACPI related.  Try checking for a BIOS update.  If your system has any ACPI drivers or software (such as system tray icons that change screen brightness or "LCD scaling"; Toshiba and Asus systems have this type of software, don't know about others) make sure you have the latest version.